# Function for GetUniquePCID .NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, function, uniqueidentifier

I need a function that returns a String, using the hardware serial numbers and mixing them together to obtain a single serial number.

I searched try a function like this but I can not find anything similar, this function need to identify a pc with a licensing system.

I only need a same value per computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you want but if i understand your question correctly, play around with the below code (Don't use the code below with Strict On) not the best of ideas but it works...

```
Private Function SystemSerialNumber() As String
    ' Get the Windows Management Instrumentation object.
    Dim wmi As Object = GetObject("WinMgmts:")

    ' Get the "base boards" (mother boards).
    Dim serial_numbers As String = ""
    Dim mother_boards As Object = _
        wmi.InstancesOf("Win32_BaseBoard")
    For Each board As Object In mother_boards
        serial_numbers &= ", " & board.SerialNumber
    Next board
    If serial_numbers.Length > 0 Then serial_numbers = _
        serial_numbers.Substring(2)

    Return serial_numbers
End Function

Private Function CpuId() As String
    Dim computer As String = "."
    Dim wmi As Object = GetObject("winmgmts:" & _
        "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
        computer & "\root\cimv2")
    Dim processors As Object = wmi.ExecQuery("Select * from " & _
        "Win32_Processor")

    Dim cpu_ids As String = ""
    For Each cpu As Object In processors
        cpu_ids = cpu_ids & ", " & cpu.ProcessorId
    Next cpu
    If cpu_ids.Length > 0 Then cpu_ids = _
        cpu_ids.Substring(2)

    Return cpu_ids
End Function
```

**Source:**
http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_get_cpu_serial_number_id.html